# Looping through a date integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have the following code:

```
<span class="bookings">
    <span class="col-md-2">
      <h4><%= time_tag(Date.today + 1.days) %></h4>
      <% @booking.each do |b| %>
        <% if b.date == Date.today + 1.days && b.type == "Hot Desk"  %>
          <% if b.desk == @hotdesk.code %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove booked-show"></span>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </span>

  <span class="bookings">
    <span class="col-md-2">
      <h4><%= time_tag(Date.today + 2.days) %></h4>
      <% @booking.each do |b| %>
        <% if b.date == Date.today + 2.days && b.type == "Hot Desk"  %>
          <% if b.desk == @hotdesk.code %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove booked-show"></span>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </span>
```

Which extends on to however many days I want to display availability of bookings for. What I would like to achieve is writing only one of these blocks of codes out and having it loop through where it says **Date.today + 1.days** and increase the value of the days by 1 each loop up to 20 or so times.

Any ideas on a way to do this to save me writing this code over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="bookings">
    <% 1.upto(YOUR_COUNT.to_i).each do |day_count| %>
    <span class="col-md-2">
      <h4><%= time_tag(Date.today + day_count.days) %></h4>
      <% @booking.each do |b| %>
        <% if b.date == Date.today + day_count.days && b.type == "Hot Desk"  %>
          <% if b.desk == @hotdesk.code %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove booked-show"></span>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    <% end %>
  </span>
```

Comment: You sir are awesome. Just added an end tag as an edit for closure. THANK YOU!

Comment: should `<span class="bookings">` be inside the first loop?

Comment: Ideally no but it was because of some css positioning I was struggling to set up (the glyphicon positioned as absolute within a relatively positioned "bookings" span) but this seemed to work.